# Change a library version at some point when a condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, speech-to-text

Is it possible in python to change a library version at runtime when a condition is met. In my case, I am using the google speech-to-text (STT). I am using the `speech_v1` but there some functionality that is only available in the beta version `speech_v1p1beta1`. I not comfortable changing completely to the beta version completely but I want to use it when some conditions are met. There are some method am using in the `speech_v1` before I need to change the version. Those method are also available in the beta version. I think it is important I make the change to the library version globally instead of within a function or a class. I will appreciate any thought. Thanks

Change library version at runtime

Answer (score 1):

if the main version(`speech_v1`) has been imported like this:

```
import google_speech
```

**You can do this:**

```
if condition:
    google_speech=__import__("google_speech_v1p1beta1")
```

**Switching back is also possible:**

```
if switch_back_condition:
    google_speech=__import__("google_speech")
```

**The above code piece will only work when running in module context**

If this is supposed to run inside a function, you have to define google_speech as a global variable:

```
def your_function_name(*your_args,**your_kwargs):
    global google_speech
    #more code, and the condition eventually
```

**IMPORTANT:**

When installing, you have to install both versions, you have to install them with different names [speech_v1==>`google_speech`;speech_v1p1beta1==>`google_speech_v1p1beta1`]

**NOTE ON INSTANCES AND OBJECTS:**

Any objects created before the library version was changed will keep the features and properties of the version they were created with, the version switch will only apply to objects newly created after the version was switched.

Lets say speech_v1 defines a class like this:

```
class Example(object):
    def func1():
        return 3
```

and speech_v1p1beta1 defines it like this:

```
class Example(object):
    def func2():
        return 5
```

If you created an instance of this class now(`obj=Example()`)

And then you switched versions(see above)

This will still work:

```
obj.func1()#3[speech_v1p1beta1:AttributeError]
```

But this will lead to an AttributeError:

```
obj.func2()#AttributeError[speech_v1p1beta1==>5]
```

You would have to reconstruct the object.

**Changing the instance library version is NOT possible.**